# Узнать имя запускаемого процесса

Tags: c#

Кто может подсказать? Хочу сделать форму, с выбором exe файла, и сохранением его в форме для дальнейшего программного запуска через  `Process.Start`
Фишка в том, что экзешник может быть любой и заранее имя запускаемого процесса мне неизвестно. А имя нужно для завершения этого процесса, когда понадобится. Есть ли возможность при запуске процесса сразу узнать его имя для дальнейшей работы с ним?

Думал сравнивать все процессы после запуска нового и таким образом вычислять новый, но во время запуска может запуститься еще какой сторонний процесс и можно завершить в итоге не тот/

Comment: Вы когда процесс запускаете, у вас есть какая то инфа о процессе при этом? Как коонкретно вы запускаете процесс?

Comment: @tym32167: Не всё так просто. Если запускаемый файл, например, Word-овский документ, или URL, то откроется Word или браузер, а создастся ли при этом дополнительный процесс — скорее всего, нет, если Word или браузер уже открыты. Или создастся временный процесс, который через IPC передаст основному процессу запрос на открытие документа.

Comment: @VladD в таких случаях сделать ничего нельзя, так как я могу какой нибудь мьютекс в разных программах определить и потом не найти будет почему процесс прервался. С другой стороны, если наш процесс ворда закрылся сам, передав управление основному процессу ворда, то сделать уже ничего нельзя - вы не сможете манирулируя процессом закрыть документ, то есть и хранить такой процесс смысла нет.

Comment: @tym32167: Ага, а я ж о чём. А в браузере за один таб могут быть ответственны несколько процессов: JS sandbox, renderer, whatever.

Comment: Ребят, конкретно для моей задачи разобрался. Я вызывал статический запуск процесса по неопытности. На деле мне нужно было создавать экземпляр Process и экземпляр ProcessStartInfo в который помещается инфа директории запуска.  Process.StartInfo =ProcessStartInfo. Для завершения все просто Process.Kill. Кстати размышления по поводу новых окон интересны. Стыдно за такой затуп, но все обошлось)) Всем спасибо

Comment: Просто не изучил метеданные и побежал сразу сюды

Answer (score 3):

Ребят, конкретно для моей задачи разобрался. Я вызывал статический запуск процесса по неопытности. На деле мне нужно было создавать экземпляр Process и экземпляр ProcessStartInfo в который помещается инфа директории запуска. Process.StartInfo =ProcessStartInfo. Для завершения все просто Process.Kill. Кстати размышления по поводу новых окон интересны. Стыдно за такой затуп, но все обошлось)) Всем спасибо.

```
string source = "C:\\Windows/System32/notepad.exe";
ProcessStartInfo myInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(source);
Process notepadProc = new Process();
notepadProc.StartInfo = myInfo;
notepadProc.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
notepadProc.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

Возвращает только имя файла. Чтобы получить директорию можно использовать

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationBase
```

Comment: Это вы получаете данные _своего_ процесса, а нужно _чужого_.